# Is there a common tool besides gpg for encrypting files in AES?

Tags: encryption, gpg

I'd like to know if there are other tools like gpg to encrypt a file using AES encryption. I'd like the encryption to be a standardized format so I can use a programming language to decrypt the file on the other end. I am aware of zip file format but thought there might be more than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be impossible to do better than GPG's decades of secure tested encryption, but there are some other encryption tools available,  ArchWiki has good info on them here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_encryption

Though they focus on disk & folder encryption you could encrypt a folder at a time, or treat each file as a "disk" if you wanted.

Block device options are:

- [dm-crypt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt) including LUKS
- loop-AES
- a TrueCrypt fork like [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html)

Stacked filesystem (folder) options are:

- [eCryptfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs) - currently user / home folder encryption on Android & many linux's
- [EncFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EncFS)

Answer (score 3):

There is a standard tool to encrypt a file: GnuPG (also called GPG). This is a standardized format, and you can call gpg from any programming language.

[If You’re Typing the Letters A-E-S Into Your Code You’re Doing It Wrong](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2009/july/if-youre-typing-the-letters-a-e-s-into-your-code-youre-doing-it-wrong/). Clearly, your requirement is not to encrypt a file using AES — otherwise it would require a specific format. So your requirement is in fact to *encrypt a file*, period. So call a file encryption tool, and let it worry about using AES.

Comment: Actually typing AES is how you do it if you're using a common library for encryption in java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796042/aes-encryption-and-decryption-with-java I appreciate the answer but I did say I was already aware of GPG.

Comment: @simgineer Read the article. And beware that there's some bad crypto code on SO. You asked whether to use something other than GPG. I'm telling you that the answer is no, you should use GPG.

Comment: @Gilles. Please justify your assertion that users "should use GPG" in preference to "something other than GPG".

Comment: @fpmurphy1 Read the article I link to. In a nutshell, it's easy to write code that uses cryptography in a way that is functionally correct but completely misses the security goal. So you should use high-level tools that don't make it completely trivial to make major mistakes about security. Those high-level tools offer an interface like “encrypt file”, not like “AES”.

Comment: @Gilles.   Rubbish.   If one were to follow your logic, users should not use most Linux utilities.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 I'm not following your logic... but DIY encryption is usually about as safe as a DIY airbag for your car; even if it looks like it might work, it's probably a false sense of security.

Answer (score 1):

`openssl` is a common  tool for encrypting/decrypting files.

Here is a simple example of how to encrypt and decrypt a file using AES and `openssl`:

```
$ cat file.pt
one
two
three
$  openssl enc -aes-256-cbc < file.pt  > file.ct
enter aes-256-cbc encryption password: XXXXXXX
Verifying - enter aes-256-cbc encryption password: XXXXXXX
$  openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d < file.ct
enter aes-256-cbc decryption password: XXXXXXX
one
two
three
$
```

Comment: No. `openssl` is a command line tool to test the OpenSSL library and, if you know what you're doing, to manage X.509 certificates. It is not a good way to encrypt files. Case in point: the way the key is generated from the password is very prone to brute force. By default, it isn't even salted, you need to pass the `-salt` option explicitly. And even then the password generation mechanism isn't slow enough (see [this thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) — password hashing and password-based key derivation are essentially the same problem).

Comment: @Gilles.  That simply is not true. `openssl` is more than "a command line tool to test the openSSL library."  Nowhere in the `openssl` manpage does it state your assertion.

Comment: @Gilles+ `openssl enc` PBE (i.e. except `-K` uppercase) is salted by default since about 2000. OTOH it is (still) only one iteration which provides no 'stretching' of the password, and it doesn't have integrity protection. And release 1.1.0 (silently) changed the default hash, making compatibility a little more difficult. And FWIW it isn't a 'standardized format' although it can still be decrypted with any reasonable 'programming language'.

Comment: Gilles and dave_thompson_085 are right, even with salt `openssl enc` isn't in the same league as gpg if you're looking for real secure tested safe encryption. [This answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31492/file-security-when-encrypting-files-directly-with-the-openssl-command-and-what/31494#31494) and it's [linked answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29106/openssl-recover-key-and-iv-by-passphrase/29139#29139) are informative. *encryption format used by OpenSSL is non-standard,  the "iteration count" is set by the enc command to 1 and cannot be changed*, etc

Comment: @Xen2050.  Putting on my "pedantic" hat, I would point out that the encryption format used by GnuPGP is also technically "non-standard."  RPC 4880 is only a draft IETF standard and "describes only the format and methods needed to read, check, generate, and write conforming packets crossing. any network.  It does not deal with storage and implementation. questions."  The subsequent draft RFC for media type literal packets, i.e. filenames, expired in 2011. Yes, the OpenPGP community has a written file format specification, but that is by no means a standard for all encryption tools.